# What are the potential side effects of directly calling a stored procedure in a BizTalk helper class?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

What are the potential side effects and risks of directly calling a SQL Server stored procedure in a BizTalk helper class?

I've been checking through some code and found examples like ...

```
private static void SaveInvoice(long id, string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("... server ..."))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("usp_SaveDocument", sqlConnection);
            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", fileName);
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    finally 
    { 
      sqlCommand.Dispose(); 
    }
}
```

which seems like a "bad smell" in terms of BizTalk development.

But are there any real risks / limitations of doing such a direct database call in the "helper" code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code wise, there's really no 'risk', it's just .Net code calling SQL Server.

However, I consider it vary bad form to do so in a BizTalk app because its, well, not the BizTalk way.  That would be a Schema, Map, SQL Adapter, etc.

The risk is that such an operation is essentially buried in the app, not where a BizTalk Developer would expect to find it.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion:

It pretty much depends on what you are trying to achieve.

- BizTalk is very good when it comes to **reliable messaging** and that is exactly what you are using when you are using adapters. When you are using helper classes, you need to know what you are doing, since it's a different technology. Often you are calling helper classes in orchestrations for example. You need to think differently or perhaps better about error handling, the impact of logic further down you business process, etc...
- BizTalk applications can be made as generic as you can imagine and the **configuration** depends pretty much on the bindings (collections of send ports/receive locations, etc...) Moving from system to system can be as simple as changing a send port URI. When doing helper classes, you need a different connection string stored somewhere. This can be BTSNTSvc64.exe.config or something else. Read: something which will make your solution more complex by adding another dependency.

So, I think that calling helper classes from orchestrations is perfectly fine for certain circumstances.

This can be the case when dealing with something you need to store which is only a small data-set from the message itself. For example ensure duplicate detection/keeping own tracking. 
Any case where you would need to store something from a message/instance which you would need to correlate on for example.

Saving an entire message into a SQL table by means of a helper class - for whatever reason - doesn't seem very good to me though. This deserves to be done by BizTalk adapters.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm concerned that having hidden database connections (and also found web service calls) in the helper, but BizTalk knows nothing of them, so there could be adverse interactions

Comment: You also have to look at what happens in high volume situations and multi-threading, i.e. is your helper class thread safe?  Does each thread open up it's own connection? That can cause issues.  There are situations however in which using a helper class is needed, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20644569/how-do-you-configure-a-biztalk-wcf-sql-adapter-to-get-data-from-a-sql-server-201

Answer (score 0):

As long as you manage your connection there wont be any issue. "using" statement is recommended even for SqlCommand, we have been doing it for long time with no issues so far.